# Getting a list of all properties in a group in API Platform

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

Using **API Platform 1.2**.

I've simplified my setup for the purpose of this question. Please excuse lack of following standards.

I have 2 entities: `Book` and `Category`. `Book` properties:

```
/**
* @Groups({book:read})
*/
$name;

/**
* @Groups({book:read})
*/
$summary;

/**
* @Groups({book:read})
*/
$category;
```

The `$category` property is mapped to a `Category` entity. `Category` has a `$categoryName` property. This is also attached to the `book:read` group.

In the GET API call this the output contains all the `Book` properties plus the `$categoryName` property. This is great

What I want to know is: Using API Platform, how would I go about getting all properties for a serialization group such as above?

I have found that I could tap into the `\ApiPlatform\Core\Metadata\Property\Factory\PropertyMetadataFactoryInterface` to get the property info but this requires knowing what classes and properties to check. Looping through all entities with a metadata lookup, then looping through all properties, performing *another* metadata lookup seems wasteful and slow.

Is there a better way to acheieve this? I basically want the same output as what the API produces by feeding am entity name and group name.